# Allow moderators to undelete comments deleted by magic words

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-abilities, deleted-comments

No, you can't *hocus pocus* a comment to be banished to the outer realms of the ether, but there is a short list of words that, if contained within a comment, cause the comment to be removed after a single flag.

Remember when we had a problem with folks brow beating other users about their accept rate? Well, guess what word was tossed into the magic cauldron? That's right, *accept(ing)*.

Earlier today on Judaism, someone wrote a comment that began with:

> I'm not accepting that [point totally irrelevant to the green check mark]

It was flagged, and deleted instantly. This isn't a *huge* problem in and of itself, though we might want to examine if we still need to fire on that particular phrase - the problem here is that a moderator could not undelete the comment. The only time a mod should be preventing from undeleting a comment is if the comment author was the one that deleted it.

Tagging this as a bug as I'm reasonably certain it's just an oversight.

To reproduce:

- Leave a comment with a magic word
- Flag it as a non mod
- Preform the diamonding ritual, channel the cosmos as a non-developer
- Weep, as the ashes of your toils lay in ruins before you, powerless to return them to former glory.

Saying *please* and reloading the page had no effect, so I don't think this is due to the INTERCAL rewrite that we just finished.

Note that this (and the linked question) talk about the "accept" example, but the bug report is about mods not being able to undelete.  Removing "accept" from the list of magic words doesn't fix this bug, just changes one way it's triggered.

Comment: Just a plea, really - remember that comments under this go right to my inbox and ... ah heck, go ahead, get on with it, I know you're going to anyway.

Comment: I'm tempted to leave a comment with every single magic word I can think of. But then I realized that would not be acceptable because it'd be all profanity. :)

Comment: while you are conjuring magic @TimPost, could you make Justin Beiber vanish, please???

Comment: @Amaterasu The incantation you're looking for there is _Deporte' Beiberiste_ - but you have to say it three times in front of a mirror in a dark bathroom after coding something in a language that starts with B.

Comment: @TimPost Was it only one flag that caused it to be removed?  I have been doing a lot of comment clean-up and it doesn't seem that _accept(ing)_ triggers an instant delete.

Comment: Related to this: would it make sense to have some sort of dashboard or record that moderators can browse that shows recently auto-deleted comments? If someone's going on an obscene tirade in comments, we don't even see that now unless someone raises a standard flag on the post where the comment(s) occurred. It might also help us detect these false positives so we could undelete them.

Comment: Is this bug going to be fixed?

Comment: This just happened again. Any update?

Comment: This just happened again... Why not just remove "accept" from the magic list if you aren't going to find a way to let us undelete?  Especially now that there is no public accept rate to yell about. At least  make it a two-flag word instead of a one flag word.

Comment: It is a two-word flag, @DoubleAA; it's *also* a single-word flag, for a different variation on the word. "Accept rate" badgering is gone, but nagging folks to accept still happens with some regularity - got an example handy of a comment that was wrongly removed?

Comment: @Shog9 Today's example info now in deleted comment on this post. Btw I said above "two-flag word", not "two-word flag" meaning make the threshold for auto deletion two flags instead of one flag. That's still quicker than waiting for 3 or 5 or whatever other systems you have in place, but also helps limit the false positives. Just an idea. Ideally mods should be able to undelete.

Comment: Changes to the mechanics of the system are much harder than changes to the triggers, @DoubleAA; of the two, mod undeletion would be the easier to implement. These resolve quite a few flags that would otherwise have to be handled manually; I'll tweak the criteria for now, but in the future a more nuanced set of checks combined with moderator oversight would probably save us more time.

Comment: @Shog9 If you say changing the number of flags to auto delete is more complicated than implementing mod undeletion, I certainly believe you. Just an idea I had.