# What causes a "Rude or offensive" comment flag to sometimes cause instant deletion?

Tags: support, comments, flags, comment-flags

Sometimes a single "Rude or offensive" comment flag cause the comment to be instantly removed. What is causing this? This just happened to me, but I don't have the contents of the comment anymore. It included profanities, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What you mean removed? From where?

Comment: Removed = Deleted from a question or answer.

Comment: The key is _it included profanities_

Comment: Edited to clarify, I thought you mean the flag itself is deleted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238835/what-is-the-se-version-of-seven-dirty-words?lq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a black list of certain words/phrases that will cause a comment to get insta-deleted when a rude/offensive flag is raised.

That is - if a comment contains one of the item in the black list and a rude/offensive flag is raised against it, it will get deleted immediately.

Comment: I assume the list is a secret?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not fit for sharing in polite society ;)

Comment: @Oded Could the non-profane words (if there are any) be shared?

Comment: @Mooseman - that would just let people circumvent them.

Comment: Can we make a white list? Sometimes people just need to be told they are complete and utter *****