# Obsolete flag handled automatically?

Tags: discussion, flags, obsolete-information

I just flagged a comment as "obsolete" in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/247647#247647). To my surprise, it was deleted immediately, just after pressing "Flag Comment".

Now I see it in my flag summary as helpful:

> [image]

Does this mean that obsolete flags are somehow handled automatically? I went through [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) but could not find any description on this.

Comment: It's possible it contained a trigger word for auto deletion on a single flag or it already had accumulated enough flags to auto-delete it.

Comment: @bluefeet it was something like "@user check update" and the comment from the initial user wasn't there anymore, so it could be. But this would mean that there is some automatic flag handling, right?

Comment: There is indeed automatic flag handling. A certain # of flags (where that # varies depending on the score of the comment, keywords it contains, etc.) will auto-delete comments.

Comment: @Shog9 oh, I just [found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/209901) it! "Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically. The number of flags needed is based on the comment's score. It currently takes "3 + (Score / 3)" flags to delete a comment."

Comment: Oh, first time I see full use of self-close-hammer. Nice! ;)

Comment: @Sha You should be [more attentive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes#comment819240_250960) :D

Comment: @nic sorry, when coming from you I'm always suspicious ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some automatic handling processes in place for comments and it sounds like you've run into one of them.

If a comment contains a [black-listed word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773), then a single flag will remove it.

The second auto-handling is based on the number of flags on a comment.  Once a comment reaches a specific threshold, it automatically deletes the comment and the flag is processed as helpful.  It's entirely possible your flag pushed this comment over the edge so it self-destructed.  See [this Meta Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757) for more details:

> Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically. The number of flags needed is based on the comment's score. It currently takes "3 + (Score / 3)" flags to delete a comment.

It has nothing to do with the type of comment flag, it is based on the number of flags a comment has on it.