# How many Obsolete votes until a comment is removed?

Tags: support, comments, flags, comment-flags, obsolete-information

I regularly flag comments as Obsolete, for example if they are pointing out a mistake in the post which has since been corrected. I think cleaning up obsolete comments is a beautiful thing, and many commenters do this on their own accord.

I'd like to know, if I flag someone else's comment as Obsolete, what exactly happens?

- If another user flags the same comment, will it be removed at that point?
  Is there a reputation requirement for the flagger?
- Are moderators alerted? I don't really want to waste their time...

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [comment flag FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/164356):

> If a comment is flagged by three users, it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it.
>
> Comments with upvotes require more flags to be deleted without moderator intervention: 1 more flag per 3 votes above 3 (i.e. number of flags = 3 + score/3).

So:

> If another user flags the same comment, will it be removed at that point?

Yes, if the comment has 3 or more flags.

> Are moderators alerted?

Yes, if the comment does not receive enough flags in time.

Comment: That is [the FAQ in duplicate I referenced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251637/245360)... It is better to flag or vote to close than to add an answer that is basically the duplicate target.